# An example of a weakly Hopfian group which is not Hopfian

Tags: group-theory

A group $G$ is *Hopfian* iff every epimorphism $f:G\to G$ is an automorphism. A ‎group ‎‎$‎‎G$ ‎is ‎*weakly ‎Hopfian* ‎if‎f every ‎r-homomorphism ‎‎$‎‎r:G\to H\cong G$ ‎is ‎an ‎isomorphism. I‎n ‎other ‎words, ‎‎$‎‎G=K\rtimes H$ ‎and ‎‎$‎‎H\cong G$ ‎imply ‎‎$‎‎K=1$.‎‎

Trivially, every Hopfian group is weakly Hopfian. I was wondering if someone could give me an example  of a weakly Hopfian group which is not Hopfian.
I particularly interested in finitely presented examples.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: r-homomorphism = homomorphism with a right inverse? Is this a standard term?

Comment: @SeanEberhard Yes. A homomorphism $f:G\to H$ of groups is an r-homomorphism if there exists a homomorphism $g:H\to G$ such that $fg=id_H$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a classical construction of Abels does the job. Fix a prime $p$, define the group $G_0$ as the group of matrices

$$\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & u_{12} & u_{13} & u_{14}\newline
0 & d_{22} & u_{23} & u_{24}\newline
0 & 0 & d_{33} & u_{34}\newline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\newline
\end{array}\right)
$$
where $u_{ij}\in\mathbf{Z}[1/p]$,
and $d_{ii}\in p^\mathbf{Z}$.
Let $e_{14}$ denote the map $x\mapsto\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&x\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$, and $G=G_0/e_{14}(\mathbf{Z})$.

Abels observed that $G$ is not Hopfian (a surjective endomorphism with kernel of order $p$ being induced by conjugation by the diagonal matrix $(p,1,1,1)$), and proved that $G_0$ and hence $G$ is finitely presented.

But $G$ is weakly Hopfian. Indeed, let $f$ be a surjective endomorphism of $G$. Since $G_0/e_{14}(\mathbf{Z}[1/p])$ is residually finite, the kernel of $f$ is contained in $e_{14}(\mathbf{Z}[1/p])/e_{14}(\mathbf{Z})$. If this were split, since it is central it would be a direct factor, but this is absurd because $e_{14}(\mathbf{Z}[1/p])\subseteq [G_0,G_0]$.

Comment: (Thanks to Sean Eberhard to point me out this question!)

Comment: It seems like you've used this example several times to answer questions I've taken interest in -- worth remembering! Why is it finitely presented?

Comment: Finite presentability is the less trivial fact. See  H. Abels. An example of a finitely presented solvable group. Homological group theory. (Proc. Sympos., Durham, 1977), pp. 205–211, London Math. Soc. Lecture Note Ser., 36, Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge-New York, 1979.

Answer (score 5):

An example is the [Prüfer group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) $G = \mathbf Z[1/p] / \mathbf Z$. The multiplication-by-$p$ map gives a nontrivial epimorphism. On the other hand every proper subgroup of $G$ is finite, so $G$ does not have the form $K \times H$ (or equivalently $K \rtimes H$ since $G$ abelian) for nontrivial $K,H \le G$.

Edit: Sorry, I missed the requirement that $G$ should be finitely presented. Maybe $\mathrm{BS}(2,3)$ is an example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Is the Prüfer group finitely presented?

Comment: @Mahtab No, it's not even finitely generated, since it's a torsion abelian group.

Comment: Is there an exmple of a finitely presented one?

Comment: I think the Baumslag--Solitar group $\mathrm{BS}(2,3)$ is probably an example.

Comment: The Baumslag--Solitar group $BS(m,n)$ is Hopfian iff $m=1$ or $m$ and $n$ have the same prime divisors. Then $BS(2,3)$ is not Hopfian. But how can I prove that $BS(2,3)$ is weakly Hopfian?

Comment: Moreover, since for each pair of integers $0<m\leq |n|$, $BS(m,n)=\langle a,b|ab^ma^{-1}=b^n\rangle$, so they are finitely presented. I'd really appreciate if you could guide me about how to prove they are weakly Hopfian.

Comment: The finitely presented condition was added after your answer was given, so no need to apologise! @Mahtab You shouldn't change questions which make current answers wrong! You could, for example, edit your question to say you are *particularly interested* in finitely presented examples - but don't nullify any given answers.

Comment: @user1729 Got it. You are right. I forgot to add it. I appologize for that. Considet it done.

Comment: @SeanEberhard I'm very sorry I edited my question to finitely presented ones. I forgot to add the condition "finitely presented" condition at the first place.

Comment: Note that $\mathrm{BS}(2,3)$ *is* a nontrivial semidirect product, since the map to its abelianization splits. I still think it is not isomorphic to a nontrivial semidirect product with itself, but I don't see how to prove it right now.